# Correct JSON structure for Google Line Chart

Tags: json, google-visualization

Trying to put together my first google line chart, with JSON api data, in this (shortened) format:

```
{"Battery Voltage, (V)":{"2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z":12.5,"2017-10-09T00:01:00.000Z":12.44,"2017-10-09T00:02:00.000Z":12.43}}
```

From what I can tell, it needs to be in the format used below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Datetime', 'Battery Voltage, (V)'],
          ['2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z',  12.50],
          ['2017-10-09T00:01:00.000Z',  12.44],
          ['2017-10-09T00:02:00.000Z',  12.43],
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Battery Voltage',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is: how do I get my json data into the correct format? ie:

```
    {
    "cols":[
        {"label":"Datetime","type":"datetime"},
        {"label":"Battery Voltage, (V)","type":"number"},
         ],
    "rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z"}{"v":12.50}
            {"c":[{"v":"2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z"}{"v":12.50}
    ]
}
```

Comment: its coming from a python script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using javascript, you can transform the json with the following snippet...

```
var chartData = [];
Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(function (column) {
  chartData.push(['Datetime', column]);
  Object.keys(jsonData[column]).forEach(function (dateValue) {
    chartData.push([new Date(dateValue), jsonData[column][dateValue]]);
  });
});
```

the above will create an array as follows...

```
[
  ["Datetime","Battery Voltage, (V)"],
  ["2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z",12.5],
  ["2017-10-09T00:01:00.000Z",12.44],
  ["2017-10-09T00:02:00.000Z",12.43]
]
```

which then can be used with static method --> `arrayToDataTable`
to create the data table

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var jsonData = {"Battery Voltage, (V)":{"2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z":12.5,"2017-10-09T00:01:00.000Z":12.44,"2017-10-09T00:02:00.000Z":12.43}};

  var chartData = [];
  Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(function (column) {
    chartData.push(['Datetime', column]);
    Object.keys(jsonData[column]).forEach(function (dateValue) {
      chartData.push([new Date(dateValue), jsonData[column][dateValue]]);
    });
  });
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 48
    },
    title: 'Battery Voltage',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="curve_chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, works well. Could I ask why the times on the graph are different to the actual data? My next step would be to get the timestamps into actual datetime, or is that necessary?